# How do i return the parent based on the value from child key?

Tags: lodash

Im trying to find a way of returning the parent(s) in an array. I have tried `pickBy` and other solutions on stack but it either return the whole parent array, or nothing.

This is how my array looks like, and i want to find the parents based on `tags`.

```
    {
        'fraga': "Question 1",
        'svar' : "This is this explanation",
        'tags' : ['knowledge'],
    },
    {
        'fraga': "Question 2",
        'svar' : "This is this explanation for question 2",
        'tags' : ['knowledge', 'code'],
    },
```

So if i want the parents with tag `knowledge` i would get both "question 1" and "question 2", but if i want the parent with tags `code` i would only get "question 2".

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple wrapper function in case you are calling it multiple times to search for multiple tags separateliy, but you could easily just use the Lodash code from within the function.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    'fraga': "Question 1",
    'svar' : "This is this explanation",
    'tags' : ['knowledge'],
  },
  {
    'fraga': "Question 2",
    'svar' : "This is this explanation for question 2",
    'tags' : ['knowledge', 'code'],
  }
];

console.log(getByTag(arr, 'knowledge'));
console.log(getByTag(arr, 'code'));


function getByTag(objectArray, tagName) {
  return _.filter(objectArray, (obj) => _.includes(obj.tags, tagName));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```